# Как правильнее обработать массив на jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Есть задача перебрать массив и в случае, если ничего не находится из того, что искали, запускать функцию.

Как это лучше сделать?

Пример кода:

```js
var a = 
[
  {i: 1},
  {i: 2},
  {i: 9}
];
var b = 5;

$.each(a, function(){
  /*если в цикле не находится (this.i === b) 
    то только тогда надо запустить функцию c(); 
    и сработать она должна не более 1го раза*/
});

var c = function(){
  alert('ok')
}
```

Интересует, скорее, как правильнее всего тут организовать такую конструкцию.

Comment: а зачем тут jquery?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration

Comment: Так булевый флаг выставляй, если объект нашелся и тогда функцию не запускай

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = [{
  i: 5
}, {
  i: 23
}, {
  i: 47
}];

var notfound = true,
  search = 7;;
a.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.i === search) {
    notfound = false;
  }
});
if (notfound) {
  console.log('your code here');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись без jQuery и сделать на чистом js:

```js
var a = [
  {i: 1},
  {i: 2},
  {i: 9}
];
var b = 5;
var call = true; // объявляем флаг для обозначения "нахождения"
var c = function() {
  alert('ok');
}
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i].i === b) { // если значение i равно b
    call = false; // переключаем флаг на false
  }
}
if (call) { // если флаг равен true
  c(); // вызываем функция c()
  console.log('Элементов с i равным '+b+' не найдено');
}
```

Comment: Автор о другом просил. Условие если не нашлось

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko спасибо, переделал

Comment: как только флаг установился в false, Нет нужды бежать по оставшейся части коллекции